# Ruby unique username generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm implementing OAuth.

The User model requires a username.
A username must by unique (`uniqueness: true`). A User cannot be created without a username or a dupe username.

When user signs up with OAuth, I'd like to generate a unique username for the user and save them. Then, give them a chance the change it.

What is the best way to generate a `unique` username for a User?

I can use something like `Faker` to do the actual name generating. But, it needs to be unique. No dupe usernames. If Faker happens to produce a dupe, the User won't be saved.

One possible implementation is to generate a name, try to save, if it fails due to name collisions, try again. If it fails again, once again try it. But I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Your database already assigns a unique ID to each user. You could therefore reserve a certain pattern for anonymous user names that incorporates the user's id, e.g. `"user-#{user.id}"` or simply `"##{user.id}"`. Just make sure that these cannot be picked as regular names and you won't have any collisions. (alternatively leave the name as `nil` and generate the anonymous / display name on the fly, maybe even in a different color)

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by:

- generating a unique string that has a low chance of collision (SecureRandom)
- have an index on the `username` field
- use an existing lookup before setting the username field
- setting the username field before creating the new user record

```
before_create :generate_unique_username

def generate_unique_username
  self.username = loop do
    unique_string = "user-#{ SecureRandom.hex(8)}"
    break unique_string unless User.where(username: unique_string).first
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If it collides, use something like `SecureRandom.rand(10000..99999)` to spice it up a bit, as in:

```
def find_unique(username)
  test_username = username

  while (User.where(username: test_username).any?)
    test_username = "#{username}#{SecureRandom.rand(10000..99999)}"
  end

  test_username
end
```

Presuming you never have 100,000 users with precisely the same name this will eventually find a gap. If you're concerned about that you can always increase it to 6, 7 or more digits.

Comment: or `User.exists?(username: test_username)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use `SecureToken` in your User model:

`has_secure_token :username`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The docs say _"... collisions are highly unlikely"_ which sounds as if it is still possible to get duplicates that way.

Answer (score 0):

For information, it is possible to generate unique names with Faker by calling `unique` method.

Example for a username :

```rb
Faker::Internet.unique.user_name
```

Comment: That's cool. But what if all Faker user_names are taken?